# Logging support in Jetty 11

Tags: jetty, slf4j

I have recently switched to Jetty 11. I'm having major problems finding logs.

On startup it gives a warning:

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
```

According to the SLF4J site, all it needs is to find an implementation in the classpath, which is there:

```
jetty-home/lib/logging/slf4j-api-2.0.5.jar
jetty-home/lib/logging/jetty-slf4j-impl-11.0.15.jar
```

Specifically, I'm trying to figure out why Jetty's transparent proxy servlet is giving Bad Gateway always. I can see that there is a

```
protected org.slf4j.Logger _log
```

instance which it tries to use for logging but there doesn't seem to be any way to actually find those messages.

Any suggestions on how to get SLF4J to detect the implementation and then write messages to some file, any file, which I can find?

Comment: Run `java -jar /path/to/jetty-home/start.jar --list-config` and copy the output to your question here.

Answer (score 0):

The logger error simply means you have no Slf4j Logger implementation in your webapp.

Keep in mind that all webapps deploy with classloader isolation from each other and the server.

Add one to your webapp's `WEB-INF/lib/` directory.